# Getting rid of hover line markers in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, dimple.js

I have code similar to this. I want to get rid of the dashed lines and show nothing but the tooltip. Is this possible? See this code for an example:

[JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/S6FLv/483/)

```
// Remove the dashed lines please
```

Hover over one of the points.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply overwrite the event listener for mouseover events on all circles. Your legend is comprised of rectangles, so it should be unaffected. After you draw your chart:

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover",null);
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pybh6g94/).